# How to display text in telugu or any other indian language in an Android Application?

Tags: android, unicode, localization

I want to display text in an Android application. I have studied the localization API in Android. Regarding that API, I understood that we can display text in only international languages like Japanese, French, English etc.. But I have tried something  like this.

I have copied Telugu text from Google and pastes it in the strings file. The issue is that the Telugu text is displayed in high-configuration Android mobiles, but not in low-configuration Android mobiles. Is there any alternate solution for displaying text in Telugu?

Comment: What about unicode I think you can use them...

Comment: Hi, i got it with using the ttf file.

Comment: @Sravani the text is not the same as the original after using the ttf font file through assets folder.What changes you did to achieve the original text?

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You just have to put in the TTF file in the assets folder, and it will show up on all the devices.

Answer (score 0):

I shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495332/how-to-display-south-indian-languages-in-android/22497074#22497074) the whole application code for how to display one text in multiple languages especially Kannada and Telugu.

Answer (score -1):

You can try embedding custom font:

http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/

Test with Telugu fonts given here:

http://salrc.uchicago.edu/resources/fonts/available/telugu/