# Change Language and get resource direction

Tags: android

if change language,

```
 config.locale = locale;
 am.updateConfiguration(config);
```

I read the flow code in here http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1798443/.
and see locale define like en-US.
but I don't know string of system will update with values-en-rUS. where is define -r?
and How system select values-en-rUS?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495332/how-to-display-south-indian-languages-in-android/22497074#22497074) or [sample app here](http://silambar.blogspot.in/2014/04/android-localization-tutorial-in-tamil.html).

Get current locale,

```
String languageToLoad = "en";
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Log.i("Locale", Locale.getDefault());
```

Configuration changes,

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Hi,Thank for your susgestion.

Comment: and I have a question. Do you know where source code define prefix 'r' in values-en-rUS?

Comment: For English labels have to add "values" folder under the res.