# How to integrate text to speech for telugu language in android application

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

I am developing the app to show some details in English, and when I click the button it speaks out that message in English,text contains numbers also. I want to speech that text in Telugu language, Is there any way to do that.The default android tts not supports Telugu language , how to use external tts engines in android applications. Please help me on this, Thank you.

Comment: check this one :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495332/how-to-display-south-indian-languages-in-android/22497074#22497074

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
    // button on click event
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            speakOut();
        }
    });
}

// shutdown tts when activity destroy
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

// It will called before TTS started
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // check status for TTS is initialized or not
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        // if TTS initialized than set language
        result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        // tts.setPitch(5); // you can set pitch level
        // tts.setSpeechRate(); //you can set speech speed rate

        // check language is supported or not
        // check language data is available or not
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Missing data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // disable button
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            // if all is good than enable button convert text to speech
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }
}

// call this method to speak text
private void speakOut() {
    String text = txtText.getText().toString();
    if (result != tts.setLanguage(Locale.US)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter right Words...... ",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        // speak given text
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

u have to set locale for that in speak out method

**NOTE: phone and eclipse should support your locale**

Comment: But, Google default tts not supported telugu language. How it will work for Telugu language.

Comment: I didn't get this and i don't understand how to use this in android app

Comment: find  **telugu.voice** file from net,add that on asset folder and see on net how to use it... thats all

Comment: I have searched over the net try to download but I can't get it, any suggestions about this