# Return a Malayam String from another class in android/java

Tags: java, android, locale

May be a very silly but i am not able to figured it out.

requirement is to print Malayalam text..
I am able to achieve in following way.

```
 class MainActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
         TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
         j.put("contain", "മലയാളം"); 
         tv.setText(j.getString("contain"));

    }
    }
```

the above is working great..but if  I am trying as below the text view prints only question marks like --> "?????"

```
    public class Language_Mapping{
        String appName = "മലയാളം";

        public String get_Data(){
        return appName;
        }
        }

  class MainActivity extends Activity{
        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             Language_Mapping obj = new Language_Mapping();
             TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
             tv.setText(obj.get_Data());

        }
        }
```

Why??

Comment: This might work [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495332/how-to-display-south-indian-languages-in-android)

Comment: Did you save your source as Unicode (e.g. UTF-8?). Did you use the same runtime environment for both code fragments? How did you define the `TextView` instance?

Comment: Have you tried using customfont? `tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),"fonts/droidsansfallback.ttf");
            tv.setTypeface(typeface);`

Comment: @Roon13 ya I have tried

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Ya My source and run time environment both are same i:e UTF-8 and about textview I have wrote the code above for it

Comment: @L-X no i dont want in that way...

Comment: I triued your code Its working fine in android studio ,If you are using android studio on the bottom Just select UTF-8

Comment: Thanks @L-X it worked

Comment: Happy to help.   :-D